# Anomaly detection on text data using one Class SVM

Tags: machine-learning, python, anomaly-detection, data-science-model

I am working on an Anomaly detection problem that is first of its kind for me. I am able to do data cleansing and train the model however I have no idea on predicting results, as it is new for me and I am running out of time.

My notebook and data is available on Kaggle here:
https://www.kaggle.com/sanjeet7/webgateway

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: link broken? @user2816085